# How to do a GQL query (using gcloud-python)

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I have a collection of Entities of one **kind**. I need to extract the **distinct** values of one property, named **p**, of these Entities.

In GQL, I would do:

`SELECT DISTINCT p from kind`

However in the gcloud-python [library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) GQL queries aren't implemented yet (see [issue-304](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/304)).

How should I do that with the tools currently available in gcloud-python ? I'm aware of a "group-by" workaround, yet the performances are terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) currently doesn't provide a way for you to do a string GQL query ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/304)), however it seems you can use the `group_by` field in the [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/overview) to accomplish the same thing.

References:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1202
- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery